# putting two tables next to each other

Tags: html

I have two HTML tables that I would like to put side by side.

I have seen previous answers where they mention that you need to specify inline-block and to float it left.

Below is an example of what both my tables have. However it still shows one table beneath the other, why?

```
"<table style ='font-size: 10pt; float: left; display: inline-block; cellpadding='3'>"
```

Comment: specify width on both

Comment: Also remove the space between `style` and `=`... And `cellpadding` isn't part of CSS, so it should be it's own attribute

Comment: `<table style="font-size: 10pt; float: left; display: inline-block;" cellpadding="3">` here you go

Comment: you can take a look at this -> https://jsfiddle.net/n08m5je1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `inline-block` on the tables, since it will change its behavior (if you need rules like `vertical-align`). But you can use `float: left;` and disable that floating after. Here is the example: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mngszbot/)

Comment: _"Don't use inline-block on the tables, since it will change its behavior (if you need rules like vertical-align)"_ - yes, but also you have to `clear` after `float`, don't you?

Comment: Well, yes, you got me :) I meant that `vertical-align` especially. I should completely re-read my answer before post, but I hope OP found it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your Mistake Is Here...

In First Table You Have to Specify `display:inline-block` and in second table use `float:left` Just Like This...

See the code in Full View :::

```html
   

    <table border="1" style="display: inline-block;">
        <tr>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table border=1 style="float:left;" cellpadding="3">
        <tr>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

<hr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add `'` between `inline-block;` and `cellpading`

Example:

```html
<table style ='font-size: 10pt; float: left; display: inline-block;' cellpadding='3' border='1'>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table style ='font-size: 10pt; float: left; display: inline-block;' cellpadding='3' border='1'>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

As experience states, Do not set styles like `float` or `display` on table elements directly. This could cause unexpected behaviors especially dealing with different versions of browsers. instead use a `div` element as table container and set your styles on the container.

```
<div class="table-container"><table></table></div>
<div class="table-container"><table></table></div>
```

And set styles

```
.table-container { display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; }
```